# Storing different Docker Images in single Docker repository

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-registry

Can I store completely different images in single Docker repository just by using different tags?

e.g `username/myrepo:software`, `username/myrepo:code`

If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The tags are of the form [url]/[user]/image[:tag].  If you can authenticate as 'user' at 'url' you can store any number of repos there with any number of tags.

In the usual case, your 'code' and 'software' tags will be related in some way, say by having a common ancestor, but there's nothing that enforces that rule.

Comment: so i cant have two completely different images under a single repo? @seanmcl